# Strength and length of Symmetric vs Asymmetric keys

Tags: cryptography, rsa, asymmetric, ecc

There are many questions surrounding the differences between symmetric and asymmetric encryption keys.  I think I've read them all at this point.  But I'm still left wondering:

**Why does a "secure" symmetric key only have to be (roughly) 256 bits, while asymmetric keys must be at least 2048 bits long to be considered "secure"?**

Does the definition of "secure" change between the encryption types?  Or is there something about specific implementations that necessitate much longer keys for asymmetric encryption schemes?